# Nested Angular directives not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been making a directive to display some HTML and handle events as it seemed sensible to keep this code reusable. This directive was placed inside a ng-repeat and worked as expected.

Now I come to add some more display logic to it: 2 modes 'grid' and 'list', and create 2 ng-repeat elements for each mode. At this point the whole thing seems to fall apart with rendering doing some unexpected stuff.

I have created a Plunkr to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/GjxOjxE7KOlvYjxCqVJj?p=preview

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('documentObject', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      object: '=',
      viewmode: '=',
    },
    templateUrl: 'storage-object.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.viewMode === 'grid') {
        scope.class = 'grid-view';
      } else {
        scope.class = 'list-view';
      }
    }
  }
}]);

app.controller('DocumentsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.browser = {
    viewMode: 'grid',
    files: [{name: 'First'}, {name: 'Second'}, {name: 'Third'}]
  };
}]);
```

index.html

```
<div ng-switch="browser.viewMode" class="filebrowser">
  <div ng-switch-when="grid">
    <div ng-repeat="file in browser.files">
      <document-object viewmode="browser.viewMode" object="file"></document-object>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table ng-switch-when="list">
    <tr ng-repeat="file in browser.files">
      <document-object viewmode="browser.viewMode" object="file"></document-object>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

storage-object.html

```
<div ng-if="viewmode == 'grid'" class="filebrowser {{ viewmode }}">
    Grid Mode: {{ viewmode }}
    <span class="file-label {{ class }}">{{ object.name }}</span>
</div>

<td ng-if="viewmode == 'list'" class="filebrowser {{ viewmode }}">
    List Mode: {{ viewmode }}
    <span class="file-label {{ class }}">{{ object.name }}</span>
</td>
```

Grid mode should only display the items as a grid, and list mode as a table. What is happening is grid mode is displaying everything and list mode is just rendering one element.

What is going on here?

Comment: Need to post a little code as this is bordering on a link-only type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/aMOsKAATd4aBl0swPik1?p=preview

you missed `<td>` tag

```
<table ng-switch-when="list">
  <tr ng-repeat="file in browser.files">
    <td> <!--here -->
      <document-object viewmode="browser.viewMode" object="file"></document-object>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The <td> tage is in the directive's template. But I see your version works. Mmmm.

Comment: @RobinElvin Basically, only th and td elements can be direct contents of tr. and in you tried put document-object as child tag

Comment: Of course, how did I not see that? Changed my code and it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are not allowed to have anything else as a direct child of a `<tr>` than a `<td>` or `<th>` element.

In your case you are having a `<document-object>` element, which causes the browser to move it around (as it is not allowed to be where it is), which in turn confuses `ng-switch`.

Wrapping `<document-object>` in `<td></td>` and chenging it's template (e.g. replacing `<td>` with `<div>`), solves the problem.

---

index.html:

```
...
<table ng-switch-when="list">
    <tr ng-repeat="file in browser.files">
        <td>
            <document-object viewmode="browser.viewMode" object="file"></document-object>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

storage-object.html:

```
...
<div ng-if="viewmode == 'list'" class="filebrowser {{ viewmode }}">
    List Mode: {{ viewmode }}
    <span class="file-label {{ class }}">{{ object.name }}</span>
</div>
```

---

See, also, this **[updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kxh3ayN9zFx2GWfKUK0L?p=preview)**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have to award to @sylwester as he got in first.

Comment: @RobinElvin: You are welcome :) It's not that you _"have to"_, but if you _want to_ that's fine. I just posted the answer (even if the solution was almost identical to sylvester's), because I believe the explanation is probably more valuable for future reference.